# Trigger and save new token on mobile browser on webpage

Tags: javascript, firebase, mobile, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase web push notification which I'm trying to run inside browsers (mainly chrome) on mobile. I'm unable to monitor token generation which happens very often for some reason, especially when phone goes idle (black screen).

According to [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#monitor-token-refresh), it says:

> The onTokenRefreshcallback fires whenever a new token is generated, so
>   calling getToken in its context ensures that you are accessing a
>   current, available registration token.

But this doesn't happen, **it doesn't fire in eg. Google Chrome on phone** like Samsung (Andorid 6.0.1). I tried multiple ways to catch it and debug, I tried sending ajax request in back-end as part of this function but request never happens of course, as onTokenRefresh simply doesn't work

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated